# How to get status code of the response from web service call

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to troubleshoot the response object I get from the web service call.

When I try `response.StatusCode` in *ItemService.cs*. Says

> does not contain definition for 'Statuscode'. Are you missing directive or assembly reference.

I would appreciate if anyone could advise me on how to catch the exact response code and error message.

ItemService.cs

```cs
public async Task<List<Item>> GetItems()
{
    var response = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Item>>("api/item");
    if(response.StatusCode)// error
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`HttpClient.GetAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-httpclient-getasync(system-string)) to return the value of `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`.

In the `HttpResponseMessage` class, it contains [`StatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.statuscode?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-httpresponsemessage-statuscode) property which is what you need.

**Updated:**
To check whether the response returns a success code, you should use the [`IsSuccessStatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode?view=net-7.0) property. Otherwise, you should compare the status code below:

```
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

Next, extract the content from the `HttpResponseMessage` with [`HttpContentJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpcontentjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-json-httpcontentjsonextensions-readfromjsonasync(system-net-http-httpcontent-system-type-system-text-json-serialization-jsonserializercontext-system-threading-cancellationtoken)).

```cs
public async Task<List<Item>> GetItems()
{
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/Item");

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);

        return new List<Item>();
    }

    return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Item>>();
}
```

---

**Reference**

[Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core (CreateClient section with demo)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#createclient)

Comment: Using  if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(response.StatusCode)) worked. Tweaking the code as edited above, Helped.

Comment: Hi, I update my answer for the checking `StatusCode` part. Thanks.